# How can I search only git tracked files with a specific file extension?

Tags: git, search, ripgrep

I'd like to search all git tracked files that 1. has an `.hs` file extension and 2. contain the word `import` in any lines.

I've tried to use `git ls-files -z | xargs -0 rg -g '*.hs' "import"` however unfortunately if you pass an explicit list of files to `rg` it seems to ignore the `-g` glob flag.

I could potentially use `grep` to use some regex lookbehind to extract files with a specific file extension, or potentially filter the output from `git ls-files -z` (ensuring we keep the null separated filenames aspect, both approaches seem a bit clunky though...

If anyone has any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I'm not misreading the question. If you want " to search all git tracked files that contain the word `import` in any lines", that should be:

```
git ls-files -z | xargs -0 grep -l import
```

If you only want to search in `*.hs` files, then:

```
git ls-files -z '*.hs' | xargs -0 grep -l import
```

Comment: Ah ls-files accepts a glob pattern itself, that likely does it! Thank you

Answer (score 3):

`git grep` can also do this for you:

```
git grep import -- '*.hs'
```

This will search for “import” in all git-tracked files matching `*.hs`, starting from the current directory.